# ManagedPolicy not updating when redeploying stack

Tags: aws-sam

I have a custom `AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy` attached to my `AWS::Serverless::Function` in SAM's template yaml. The managed policy has a resource allowed to it via a `!Sub` of a parameter. When I redeploy this stack after changing the parameter value, it doesn't actually update my managed policy in the changeset. Any ideas?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 # allows for AWS SAM defined objects
Description: Serverless for Data Science Platform

Parameters:
  MyLambdaParam:
    Type: String
    Default: "sagemaker-endpoint-name"
    Description: SageMaker endpoint's name

...

  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: mylambda/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      FunctionName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-ODSP"
      Description: Transforms input and passes along to SageMaker for MyLambda
      Policies:
        - KMSDecryptPolicy:
            KeyId: !Ref KMSKeyId
        - !Ref SageMakerInvokeEndpointPolicy

...

  SageMakerInvokeEndpointPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          -   Effect: "Allow"
              Action:
                - "sagemaker:InvokeEndpoint"
              Resource: 
                - !Sub "arn:aws:sagemaker:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:endpoint/${MyLambdaParam}"
```